# Rails 3.1 asset pipeline: Where is the location of the compiled files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

`vendor/assets/` is empty. Can't seem to find the compiled files anywhere.

EDIT: Unfortunately they are not in public/assets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

they write to 'public/assets'.

If you don't precompile and let rails serve assets on the fly, then they write on the first request of each action to 'tmp/cache/assets'.

The asset pipeline Rails guide calls it [live compilation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#live-compilation).

Answer (score 2):

http://ryanbigg.com/guides/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

They should be in public/assets when compiled and are appended with an md5 hash.

vendor/assets is where I would recommend putting assets that are not maintained by you.

Answer (score 0):

They should be in public/assets